# How to check if a variable is a ctypes type?

Tags: python, ctypes

I would like to check if a variable is a `ctypes` type. In the documentation, it is stated that they all inherits the `ctypes._CData` type. However, this is a non-public class (and that prevent to use `isinstance` or `issubclass`).

What is the recommended way to go then ?

This could also be useful for type hinting, and argument type checking

Comment: Checking `isinstance(var, _SimpleCData)` seems to work, is that adequate?

Comment: Sounds more like an *XY Problem*. Why do you need this functionality? *\_CData* (and *\_SimpleCData*) can do the trick, but they are actually just workaorunds (as they are private). Don't abuse *CTypes* by "writing *C* programs in *Python*". Do the heavy lifting in *C* and then wrap  it in *Python*.

Comment: I need it for two things : 1) type hinting, 2) multi-signature function (if it's a ctype, do this, if not do that).

This is kind of a useful exception of the "write C programs in python" : I am actually writing a C++ code generator. And defining the structs in python gets me a free Python binding for using the produced lib in C(++) and Python

Comment: @101 _CData seems not even accessible. _SimpleCData is as you said private... My current workaround is to try a ctypes.sizeof() on the type, if it throws an error, it is not a ctype type... But this is still hacky... Maybe should I write an issue on the python bugtracker ?

Comment: Does it matter that it's private? It does work. And it seems like any solution will be at least a tad hacky.